clangd cannot find ue5 header files
I used UE5 to generate a C++ class and opened it with VSC. Clangd prompted that it could not find "coreminimal.h", but the project could be generated normally.
ue seems to automatically generate a c_cpp_properties.json file and two compile_commands files, which are as follows：
c_cpp_properties.json:
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "obstacleassaultEditor Editor Win64 Development (obstacleassault)",
        "compilerPath": "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++20",
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "compileCommands": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_obstacleassault.json"
    },
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "compilerPath": "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++20",
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "compileCommands": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_Default.json"
    }
],
"version": 4

}
compileCommands_Default.json:
[
{
    "file": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\Source\\obstacleassault\\MovingPlatform.cpp",
    "arguments": [
        "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "@E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_Default\\obstacleassault.1.rsp"
    ],
    "directory": "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source"
},
{
    "file": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\Source\\obstacleassault\\MovingPlatform.h",
    "arguments": [
        "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "@E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_Default\\obstacleassault.1.rsp"
    ],
    "directory": "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source"
},
{
    "file": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\Source\\obstacleassault\\obstacleassault.Build.cs",
    "arguments": [
        "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "@E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_Default\\obstacleassault.1.rsp"
    ],
    "directory": "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source"
},
{
    "file": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\Source\\obstacleassault\\obstacleassault.cpp",
    "arguments": [
        "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "@E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_Default\\obstacleassault.1.rsp"
    ],
    "directory": "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source"
},
{
    "file": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\Source\\obstacleassault\\obstacleassault.h",
    "arguments": [
        "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "@E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_Default\\obstacleassault.1.rsp"
    ],
    "directory": "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source"
}

]
compileCommands_obstacleassault.json:
[
{
    "file": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\Source\\obstacleassault\\MovingPlatform.cpp",
    "arguments": [
        "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "@E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_obstacleassault\\obstacleassault.1.rsp"
    ],
    "directory": "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source"
},
{
    "file": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\Source\\obstacleassault\\MovingPlatform.h",
    "arguments": [
        "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "@E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_obstacleassault\\obstacleassault.1.rsp"
    ],
    "directory": "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source"
},
{
    "file": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\Source\\obstacleassault\\obstacleassault.Build.cs",
    "arguments": [
        "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "@E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_obstacleassault\\obstacleassault.1.rsp"
    ],
    "directory": "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source"
},
{
    "file": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\Source\\obstacleassault\\obstacleassault.cpp",
    "arguments": [
        "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "@E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_obstacleassault\\obstacleassault.1.rsp"
    ],
    "directory": "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source"
},
{
    "file": "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\Source\\obstacleassault\\obstacleassault.h",
    "arguments": [
        "D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "@E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\.vscode\\compileCommands_obstacleassault\\obstacleassault.1.rsp"
    ],
    "directory": "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source"
}

]
the rsp file specified in the json file contains the parent folder path of that header file
and the output of clangd was:
I[17:08:47.937] clangd version 18.1.3 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project c13b7485b87909fcf739f62cfa382b55407433c0)
I[17:08:47.938] Features: windows+grpc
I[17:08:47.938] PID: 43328
I[17:08:47.938] Working directory: e:\unreal\project\obstacleassault\obstacleaasault
I[17:08:47.938] argv[0]: D:\program\clangd-windows-18.1.3_7\clangd_18.1.3\bin\clangd.exe
I[17:08:47.942] Starting LSP over stdin/stdout
I[17:08:47.942] <-- initialize(0)
I[17:08:47.952] --> reply:initialize(0) 9 ms
I[17:08:47.999] <-- initialized
I[17:08:48.001] <-- textDocument/didOpen
I[17:08:48.003] Failed to find compilation database for e:\unreal\project\obstacleassault\obstacleaasault\Source\obstacleassault\MovingPlatform.h
I[17:08:48.003] ASTWorker building file e:\unreal\project\obstacleassault\obstacleaasault\Source\obstacleassault\MovingPlatform.h version 1 with command clangd fallback
[e:\unreal\project\obstacleassault\obstacleaasault\Source\obstacleassault]
"D:\\program\\mingw64\\bin\\clang" -xobjective-c++-header "-resource-dir=D:\\program\\clangd-windows-18.1.3_7\\clangd_18.1.3\\lib\\clang\\18" -- "e:\\unreal\\project\\obstacleassault\\obstacleaasault\\Source\\obstacleassault\\MovingPlatform.h"
I[17:08:48.012] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:48.024] Built preamble of size 239300 for file e:\unreal\project\obstacleassault\obstacleaasault\Source\obstacleassault\MovingPlatform.h version 1 in 0.01 seconds
I[17:08:48.025] --> workspace/semanticTokens/refresh(0)
I[17:08:48.025] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:48.026] <-- reply(0)
I[17:08:48.027] Indexing c++14 standard library in the context of e:\unreal\project\obstacleassault\obstacleaasault\Source\obstacleassault\MovingPlatform.h
I[17:08:48.043] --> textDocument/publishDiagnostics
I[17:08:48.043] --> textDocument/inactiveRegions
I[17:08:48.043] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:48.078] <-- textDocument/documentLink(1)
I[17:08:48.079] --> reply:textDocument/documentLink(1) 0 ms
I[17:08:48.079] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:48.088] <-- textDocument/inlayHint(2)
I[17:08:48.088] --> reply:textDocument/inlayHint(2) 0 ms
I[17:08:48.088] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:48.089] <-- textDocument/semanticTokens/full(3)
I[17:08:48.090] --> reply:textDocument/semanticTokens/full(3) 0 ms
I[17:08:48.090] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:48.453] <-- $/setTrace
I[17:08:48.453] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[17:08:48.579] <-- $/setTrace
I[17:08:48.579] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[17:08:48.684] <-- $/setTrace
I[17:08:48.684] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[17:08:48.688] <-- textDocument/documentLink(4)
I[17:08:48.688] --> reply:textDocument/documentLink(4) 0 ms
I[17:08:48.688] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:48.694] <-- $/setTrace
I[17:08:48.694] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[17:08:49.056] <-- $/setTrace
I[17:08:49.056] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[17:08:49.064] <-- textDocument/foldingRange(5)
I[17:08:49.065] --> reply:textDocument/foldingRange(5) 0 ms
I[17:08:49.065] <-- textDocument/documentSymbol(6)
I[17:08:49.066] --> reply:textDocument/documentSymbol(6) 0 ms
I[17:08:49.066] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:49.094] <-- textDocument/inlayHint(7)
I[17:08:49.094] --> reply:textDocument/inlayHint(7) 0 ms
I[17:08:49.094] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:49.107] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[17:08:49.196] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[17:08:49.223] <-- textDocument/foldingRange(8)
I[17:08:49.223] --> reply:textDocument/foldingRange(8) 0 ms
I[17:08:49.230] <-- textDocument/documentSymbol(9)
I[17:08:49.230] --> reply:textDocument/documentSymbol(9) 0 ms
I[17:08:49.230] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:49.233] <-- textDocument/semanticTokens/full/delta(10)
I[17:08:49.233] --> reply:textDocument/semanticTokens/full/delta(10) 0 ms
I[17:08:49.233] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:49.233] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[17:08:49.234] <-- textDocument/documentLink(11)
I[17:08:49.234] --> reply:textDocument/documentLink(11) 0 ms
I[17:08:49.234] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:49.235] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[17:08:49.256] Indexed c++14 standard library (incomplete due to errors): 12180 symbols, 1150 filtered
I[17:08:49.272] <-- textDocument/foldingRange(12)
I[17:08:49.273] --> reply:textDocument/foldingRange(12) 0 ms
I[17:08:49.557] <-- textDocument/documentSymbol(13)
I[17:08:49.557] --> reply:textDocument/documentSymbol(13) 0 ms
I[17:08:49.557] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:50.107] <-- textDocument/documentSymbol(14)
I[17:08:50.107] --> reply:textDocument/documentSymbol(14) 0 ms
I[17:08:50.107] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:50.254] <-- $/setTrace
I[17:08:50.254] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[17:08:51.100] <-- textDocument/inlayHint(15)
I[17:08:51.100] --> reply:textDocument/inlayHint(15) 0 ms
I[17:08:51.100] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:51.318] <-- textDocument/foldingRange(16)
I[17:08:51.318] --> reply:textDocument/foldingRange(16) 0 ms
I[17:08:51.393] <-- textDocument/documentSymbol(17)
I[17:08:51.393] --> reply:textDocument/documentSymbol(17) 0 ms
I[17:08:51.393] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:52.102] <-- textDocument/definition(18)
I[17:08:52.102] --> reply:textDocument/definition(18) 0 ms
I[17:08:52.102] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[17:08:52.127] <-- textDocument/definition(19)
I[17:08:52.127] --> reply:textDocument/definition(19) 0 ms
I[17:08:52.127] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus

I created compile_commands.json in the Source folder and copied the contents of compileCommands_obstacle.json into it:

This solved the problem of the header files not being found but caused other problems：

outlog of clangd:
I[20:00:22.539] clangd version 18.1.3 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project c13b7485b87909fcf739f62cfa382b55407433c0)
I[20:00:22.540] Features: windows+grpc
I[20:00:22.540] PID: 29612
I[20:00:22.540] Working directory: e:\unreal\project\obstacle
I[20:00:22.540] argv[0]: D:\program\clangd-windows-18.1.3_7\clangd_18.1.3\bin\clangd.exe
I[20:00:22.546] Starting LSP over stdin/stdout
I[20:00:22.546] <-- initialize(0)
I[20:00:22.556] --> reply:initialize(0) 9 ms
I[20:00:22.557] <-- initialized
I[20:00:22.559] <-- textDocument/didOpen
I[20:00:22.561] Loaded compilation database from e:\unreal\project\obstacle\Source\compile_commands.json
I[20:00:22.561] --> window/workDoneProgress/create(0)
I[20:00:22.561] Enqueueing 5 commands for indexing
I[20:00:22.562] <-- reply(0)
I[20:00:22.562] --> $/progress
I[20:00:22.562] --> $/progress
I[20:00:22.562] ASTWorker building file e:\unreal\project\obstacle\Source\obstacle\MovingPlatform.h version 1 with command 
[E:\epic\UE_5.4\Engine\Source]
"D:\\program\\vs\\2022community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe" --driver-mode=cl 
/FI "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacle\\Intermediate\\Build\\Win64\\x64\\UnrealEditor\\Development\\obstacle\\Definitions.obstacle.h" 
/FI "E:\\unreal\\project\\obstacle\\Intermediate\\Build\\Win64\\x64\\obstacleEditor\\Development\\UnrealEd\\SharedPCH.UnrealEd.Project.ValApi.Cpp20.InclOrderOldest.h" 
/I "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source" 
/I "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Intermediate\\Build\\Win64\\UnrealEditor\\Inc\\Engine\\UHT"
...........
/I "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source\\ThirdParty\\LibTiff\\Source\\Win64" 
/I "E:\\epic\\UE_5.4\\Engine\\Source\\ThirdParty\\LibTiff\\Source" "-resource-dir=D:\\program\\clangd-windows-18.1.3_7\\clangd_18.1.3\\lib\\clang\\18" -- "e:\\unreal\\project\\obstacle\\Source\\obstacle\\MovingPlatform.h"
I[20:00:22.571] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[20:00:22.666] <-- textDocument/documentLink(1)
I[20:00:22.667] <-- textDocument/inlayHint(2)
I[20:00:22.692] <-- $/setTrace
I[20:00:22.692] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[20:00:22.695] <-- $/setTrace
I[20:00:22.695] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[20:00:23.087] <-- textDocument/foldingRange(3)
I[20:00:23.128] --> reply:textDocument/foldingRange(3) 41 ms
I[20:00:23.157] <-- textDocument/codeAction(4)
I[20:00:23.158] --> $/progress
I[20:00:23.158] --> $/progress
I[20:00:23.158] --> $/progress
E[20:00:23.182] Indexing E:\unreal\project\obstacle\Source\obstacle\obstacle.Build.cs failed: Couldn't build compiler invocation
I[20:00:23.182] --> $/progress
I[20:00:23.184] <-- $/setTrace
I[20:00:23.184] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[20:00:23.236] <-- $/setTrace
I[20:00:23.236] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[20:00:23.277] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[20:00:23.281] <-- textDocument/codeAction(5)
I[20:00:23.368] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[20:00:23.428] <-- textDocument/codeAction(6)
I[20:00:23.457] <-- $/setTrace
I[20:00:23.457] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[20:00:23.460] <-- $/setTrace
I[20:00:23.460] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[20:00:23.461] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[20:00:23.461] <-- textDocument/documentLink(7)
I[20:00:23.462] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[20:00:23.462] <-- textDocument/codeAction(8)
I[20:00:23.463] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[20:00:23.464] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[20:00:23.464] <-- textDocument/documentLink(9)
I[20:00:23.464] <-- $/setTrace
I[20:00:23.464] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[20:00:23.465] <-- textDocument/semanticTokens/full(10)
I[20:00:23.465] <-- textDocument/foldingRange(11)
I[20:00:23.465] --> reply:textDocument/foldingRange(11) 0 ms
I[20:00:23.466] <-- textDocument/documentSymbol(12)
I[20:00:24.749] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[20:00:24.786] <-- textDocument/codeAction(13)
I[20:00:24.786] <-- textDocument/documentSymbol(14)
I[20:00:24.840] <-- $/cancelRequest
I[20:00:24.841] <-- textDocument/codeAction(15)
I[20:00:24.841] <-- $/setTrace
I[20:00:24.841] unhandled notification $/setTrace
I[20:00:24.880] Built preamble of size 16125004 for file e:\unreal\project\obstacle\Source\obstacle\MovingPlatform.h version 1 in 2.31 seconds
I[20:00:24.883] Indexing c17 standard library in the context of e:\unreal\project\obstacle\Source\obstacle\MovingPlatform.h
I[20:00:24.884] --> workspace/semanticTokens/refresh(1)
I[20:00:24.885] <-- reply(1)
I[20:00:24.944] --> textDocument/publishDiagnostics
I[20:00:24.944] --> textDocument/inactiveRegions
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/documentLink(1) 2277 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/inlayHint(2) 2277 ms
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/codeAction(4) 1786 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/codeAction(5) 1662 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/codeAction(6) 1516 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/documentLink(7) 1482 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/codeAction(8) 1481 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/documentLink(9) 1480 ms
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/semanticTokens/full(10) 1479 ms
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/documentSymbol(12) 1478 ms
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/codeAction(13) 158 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/documentSymbol(14) 157 ms
I[20:00:24.944] --> reply:textDocument/codeAction(15) 103 ms
I[20:00:24.945] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
[Error - 8:00:24 PM] Request textDocument/documentLink failed.
[object Object]
[Error - 8:00:24 PM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
[object Object]
[Error - 8:00:24 PM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
[object Object]
[Error - 8:00:24 PM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
[object Object]
[Error - 8:00:24 PM] Request textDocument/documentLink failed.
[object Object]
[Error - 8:00:24 PM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
[object Object]
[Error - 8:00:24 PM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
[object Object]
I[20:00:25.013] <-- textDocument/codeAction(16)
I[20:00:25.013] --> reply:textDocument/codeAction(16) 0 ms
I[20:00:25.013] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus


Your image adds zero information to the question.

Isn't it supposed to be called compile_commands.json? Check if this file is being found: close all tabs other than your single source file, press Ctrl+Shift+P -> Reload Window, and look in Output -> Clangd for logs. It will tell you if it can find compile_commands.json or not.

@n.m.couldbeanAI ¯\(ツ)/¯ I don't mind it. At least we know that OP correctly diagnosed this to be a Clangd error (and not a compiler error or something).

@n.m.couldbeanAI I'm sorry about that and have edited the question.

@HolyBlackCat Thank you for your suggestions, but I am relatively new to clangd and compile_commands.json files, so I hope to get more suggestions and help from you.

Clangd doesn't respect c_cpp_properties.json. Failed to find compilation database for ... suggests that it didn't find no compiler_commands.json. I'd just copy the json to give it the correct name for now, or specify the correct location as specified here: https://clangd.llvm.org/config#compilationdatabase

@HolyBlackCat I did what you said, and it solved the problem of not being able to find the header files, but it caused other problems, which did not show up after I changed clangd to intellisense. What is the reason for this?

Unsure, you'd have to debug. You can debug those errors by grabbing the compiler command from the log and trying to compile this file with Clang. It should result in the same errors, which you can then try to fix.

@HolyBlackCat 圣黑猫 i I think I know the reason. It's probably because the cpp syntax in Unreal is different from the general one, and clangd can't recognize it. For example, clangd even thinks that the macro UCLASS() should be followed by ;. Anyway, thank you for your help.

@HolyBlackCat The good news is that I have found a blog that solves this problem

this extension for vsc on github can solve the problem：
https://github.com/boocs/unreal-clangd

Currently doesn't support UE source files but that should be coming soon™.

i also hope so qwq
